# Cyclops, is it his gaze direction or the direction of his face? (X-men)

Tags: marvel, x-men, cyclops

Does Cyclops' eye beam follow his gaze or the direction his face is pointing? E.g. if Cyclops crossed his eyes, would two beams go in different directions (or, cooler, would the beam disperse)? If he looked at the end of his nose, would he blow his nose off, or would the beam just shoot straight out?

Comment: He's immune to his own blasts (and he and his brother are immune to each others blasts), so no, he can't accidentally blow his own nose off.

Comment: Rather similar to this question:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17580/how-can-cyclops-miss-with-his-optic-blast

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell,  so long as he's wearing his visor the beam follows the direction of his head:

[image: Cyclops and his eye beams throughout the years]

That seems to be the point of them.

But the beams do seem to come *directly* from his eyes

[image: Eye beams warming up]

But I've not seen a single image of Cyclops glancing one way or the other,  regardless of the trickshots he pulls off:

[image: Cyclops hustling at pool]

So my best answer is: undetermined.